# How can I get IP address of server in client system?

Tags: c#, server, ip

I need to show IP address of server in client system . would you please help me how can I do this in C#?

Comment: For querying the server you need to know it's IP address, isn't it?

Comment: Please share some code you trying to write/fix and explain what you're trying to achieve. As Dmitry stated, if going to send requests to server you have to know either it's ip or it's address (which converts to ip by dns)

Comment: I dont have any code , I just founded some code that returns IP of my system but I want to get IP of my server, maybe by socket programming or ...? is there any way ? or its impossible to get server's IP from client system ? I even dont know my server name